# Index was outside the bounds of the array. How to solve this problem?

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace _2._1
{
class Program
{
    public struct nariai
    {
        public string vardas;
        public string pavarde;
        public double pinigai;
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader failas = new StreamReader("nariai.txt");
        string a = failas.ReadLine();
        int nariuKiekis = int.Parse(a);
        nariai[] narys = new nariai[nariuKiekis];
        string[] info = new string[nariuKiekis];
        for (int i = 0; i < nariuKiekis; i++)
        {
            info[i] = failas.ReadLine();
            string[] informacija = info[i].Split(' ');
            narys[i].vardas = informacija[i];
            narys[i].pavarde = informacija[i + 1];
            narys[i].pinigai = double.Parse(informacija[i + 2]);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", narys[0].vardas, narys[0].pavarde, narys[0].pinigai);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My file looks like that. [image: file]

And i am getting this error in the console. [image: console]

Why it isn't showing the "Almeda Norkute 25.70" ?

Comment: Could you add the content of file and error description to the question, so that it remains when question is solved and links you added will became broken?

Comment: Why are you using `i` with `informacija`?

Comment: If you come across this message, step through your code over the line , where it says the error occurs and check the values of your indices. Then think about why they have the values they have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
narys[i].vardas = informacija[i];
narys[i].pavarde = informacija[i + 1];
narys[i].pinigai = double.Parse(informacija[i + 2]);
```

write

```
narys[i].vardas = informacija[0];
narys[i].pavarde = informacija[1];
narys[i].pinigai = double.Parse(informacija[2]);
```

Your `informacija` contains one line and one line always has 3 items in your example. If you need i to access these you get the error because you're trying to access position which are not existing.

And use

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", narys[i].vardas, narys[i].pavarde, narys[i].pinigai);
```

Otherwise you would write always the first record in the console ;)

Comment: Then i'm getting this http://www.part.lt/img/ae3e8916ecbc05fbbe9a68bcd3099ca895.PNG

Comment: Really they should be checking to make sure `informacija` has a length of 3 as well.

Comment: I need: Lukas Velicka 20.50
Almeda Norkute 25.70

Comment: Have a look at my edit. You were using the wrong index in your 'Console.WriteLine' call, too.

Comment: Single-Space separated CSV-like format isn't really the best of ideas to store data. Consider using actual csv, XML or JSON. That would be my advice. It will save you from headaches if you ever need to add information. @LukasVelička

Comment: @Fildor The whole file format is not really good but that was not the question and maybe he can't change it. He does not need the count of the entries in the file, too (just another example).

Comment: @LukasVelička If it solved it then why does is not have a check mark?

Comment: @MightyBadaboom That's why I wrote a comment and "That would be my advice."

Comment: @Fildor Ok, good point.

Comment: @paparazzo isn't there a min time that has to pass before you can accept any answer? I thought so ... (at least for rep 1 users)

Comment: @Fildor 15 Minutes as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Instead of informacija[i], informacija[i+1] and informacija[i+2], use informacija[0],informacija[1] and informacija[2] respectively.

And also use index **i** in console.writeline statement.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nariuKiekis; i++)
            {
                info[i] = failas.ReadLine();
                string[] informacija = info[i].Split(' ');
                narys[i].vardas = informacija[0];
                narys[i].pavarde = informacija[1];
                narys[i].pinigai = double.Parse(informacija[2]);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", narys[i].vardas, narys[i].pavarde, narys[i].pinigai);
            }
```